# How do I use 'may', 'might' and 'could' in question forms?

Tags: grammar

I'm creating a lesson on 'may', 'might',  and could and just encountered the following (BBC)

Do you think Catherine might have curry for dinner?

Do you think Catherine may have curry for dinner?

Do you think Catherine could have curry for dinner?

The first sentence sounds fine, while the other two sound rather awkward to my ears. Are my instincts correct here? I would prefer to just give the student the first sentence as the correct question form for possibilities. Other examples include:

Do you think Asda might have Spinach?

Do you think Bjork might release another album this year?

I would not substitute 'might' for 'have' or 'could', as it does not sound idiomatic at all.

Comment: They sound awkward because they mean something different, and the contexts in which they are meaningful are uncommon and unlikely to occur in most conversations. And this is not a use of _may_ or _might_ "in question form", btw -- it's just a tensed complement clause, the direct object of _think_. The modals are in a subordinate clause, while the question is in the main clause.

Comment: "Do you think [noun] could [verb]" reads like a request for permission rather than an inquiry as to whether something is likely.